# Finding out the duplicate element in an array

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

There is an array of size n and the elements contained in the array are between 1 and n-1 such that each element occurs once and just one element occurs more than once.  We need to find this element.

Though this is a very FAQ, I still haven't found a proper answer.  Most suggestions are that I should add up all the elements in the array and then subtract from it the sum of all the indices, but this won't work if the number of elements is very large.  It will overflow.  There have also been suggestions regarding the use of XOR gate `dup = dup ^ arr[i] ^ i`, which are not clear to me.

I have come up with this algorithm which is an enhancement of the addition algorithm and will reduce the chances of overflow to a great extent!

```
for i=0 to n-1
  begin :
    diff = A[i] - i;
    sum  = sum + diff;
  end
```

`diff` contains the duplicate element, but using this method I am unable to find out the index of the duplicate element.  For that I need to traverse the array once more which is not desirable.  Can anyone come up with a better solution that does not involve the addition method or the XOR method works in O(n)?

Comment: This is just an easier case of the problem in *[Finding duplicates in O(n) time and O(1) space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5739024/134633)*

Comment: "For that I need to traverse the array once more which is not desirable" Why is that not desirable? Traversing the array a second time won't change the complexity of the algorithm.

Comment: @caf: The solutions there modify the array which seems undesirable here.

Comment: @sepp2k: It wont change the complexity, but it would make the algorithm slower anyway (say, compared to the one-pass algorithm).

Comment: *"diff contains the duplicate element"*.  How exactly? At the end, `diff == (A[n-1] - (n-1))`. and what is the use of `sum`? You're not *using* the final result anywhere.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There are many ways that you can think about this problem, depending on the constraints of your problem description.

**If you know for a fact that exactly one element is duplicated**, then there are many ways to solve this problem.  One particularly clever solution is to use the bitwise XOR operator.  XOR has the following interesting properties:

1. XOR is associative, so (x ^ y) ^ z = x ^ (y ^ z)
2. XOR is commutative: x ^ y = y ^ x
3. XOR is its own inverse: x ^ y = 0 iff x = y
4. XOR has zero as an identity: x ^ 0 = x

Properties (1) and (2) here mean that when taking the XOR of a group of values, it doesn't matter what order you apply the XORs to the elements.  You can reorder the elements or group them as you see fit.  Property (3) means that if you XOR the same value together multiple times, you get back zero, and property (4) means that if you XOR anything with 0 you get back your original number.  Taking all these properties together, you get an interesting result: if you take the XOR of a group of numbers, the result is the XOR of all numbers in the group that appear an odd number of times.  The reason for this is that when you XOR together numbers that appear an even number of times, you can break the XOR of those numbers up into a set of pairs.  Each pair XORs to 0 by (3), and th combined XOR of all these zeros gives back zero by (4).  Consequently, all the numbers of even multiplicity cancel out.

To use this to solve the original problem, do the following.  First, XOR together all the numbers in the list.  This gives the XOR of all numbers that appear an odd number of times, which ends up being all the numbers from 1 to (n-1) except the duplicate.  Now, XOR this value with the XOR of all the numbers from 1 to (n-1).  This then makes all numbers in the range 1 to (n-1) that were not previously canceled out cancel out, leaving behind just the duplicated value.  Moreover, this runs in O(n) time and only uses O(1) space, since the XOR of all the values fits into a single integer.

In your original post you considered an alternative approach that works by using the fact that the sum of the integers from 1 to n-1 is n(n-1)/2.  You were concerned, however, that this would lead to integer overflow and cause a problem.  On most machines you are right that this would cause an overflow, but (on most machines) this is not a problem because arithmetic is done using fixed-precision integers, commonly 32-bit integers.  When an integer overflow occurs, the resulting number is not meaningless.  Rather, it's just the value that you would get if you computed the actual result, then dropped off everything but the lowest 32 bits.  Mathematically speaking, this is known as modular arithmetic, and the operations in the computer are done modulo 2<sup>32</sup>.  More generally, though, let's say that integers are stored modulo k for some fixed k.

Fortunately, many of the arithmetical laws you know and love from normal arithmetic still hold in modular arithmetic.  We just need to be more precise with our terminology.  We say that x is congruent to y modulo k (denoted x ≡<sub>k</sub> y) if x and y leave the same remainder when divided by k.  This is important when working on a physical machine, because when an integer overflow occurs on most hardware, the resulting value is congruent to the true value modulo k, where k depends on the word size.  Fortunately, the following laws hold true in modular arithmetic:

For example:

1. If x ≡<sub>k</sub> y and w ≡<sub>k</sub> z, then x + w ≡<sub>k</sub> y + z
2. If x ≡<sub>k</sub> y and w ≡<sub>k</sub> z, then xw ≡<sub>k</sub> yz.

This means that if you want to compute the duplicate value by finding the total sum of the elements of the array and subtracting out the expected total, everything will work out fine even if there is an integer overflow because standard arithmetic will still produce the same values (modulo k) in the hardware.  That said, you could also use the XOR-based approach, which doesn't need to consider overflow at all. :-)

**If you are not guaranteed that exactly one element is duplicated, but you can modify the array of elements,** then there is a beautiful algorithm for finding the duplicated value.  [This earlier SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739024/finding-duplicates-in-on-time-and-o1-space/5739336#5739336) describes how to accomplish this.  Intuitively, the idea is that you can try to sort the sequence using a [bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort), where the array of elements itself is recycled to hold the space for the buckets as well.

**If you are not guaranteed that exactly one element is duplicated, and you cannot modify the array of elements,** then the problem is much harder.  This is a classic (and hard!) interview problem that reportedly took Don Knuth 24 hours to solve.  The trick is to reduce the problem to an instance of [cycle-finding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection) by treating the array as a function from the numbers 1-n onto 1-(n-1) and then looking for two inputs to that function.  However, the resulting algorithm, called [Floyd's cycle-finding algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%27s_cycle-finding_algorithm#Tortoise_and_hare), is extremely beautiful and simple.  Interestingly, it's the same algorithm you would use to detect a cycle in a linked list in linear time and constant space.  I'd recommend looking it up, since it periodically comes up in software interviews.

For a complete description of the algorithm along with an analysis, correctness proof, and Python implementation, check out **[this implementation](http://keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=find-duplicate)** that solves the problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: A interesting note: xor is the only function (up to isomorphism) with those properties. In other words, countably infinite groups such that every non-identity element has order 2 are isomorphic. Finite groups with order n and every non-identity element has order 2 are isomorphic.

Comment: @ChaoXu- Do you have a reference I could check out about that?  Also, why doesn't the proof work for uncountably infinite sets?

Comment: For finite case, use fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups, we have all finite group with each non-identity element of order 2 isomorphic to (Z_2)^n for some n, and + in Z_2 is the same as xor. (this shows order of such groups must be 2^n too). For the countable infinite case, I have wrote up a proof using group presentations: http://chaoxuprime.com/2011/06/countably-infinite-group-such-that-every-element-has-order-2-are-isomorphic

Comment: @templatetypedef Yes, it generalizes to even higher cardinalities too. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17054/group-where-every-element-is-order-2

Comment: Such a beautiful answer. Can anyone help me to understand that modular arithmetic paragraph?

Answer (score 2):

Adding the elements is perfectly fine you just have to take mod(%) of the intermediate aggregate when calculating the sum of the elements and the expected sum. For the mod operation you can use something like 2n. You also have to fix the value after substraction.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?  I'm not familiar with this solution and can't quite tell what you're trying to do.  Could you post a more detailed algorithm and correctness proof?

Comment: This is an online algorithm. I'm using the sum of elements solution described by the OP, just using modulo arithmetic so there's no overflow. You know the sum of numbers from 1 to n-1. The array contains n numbers, one element repeated, so just take their sum, substract sum 1->n-1 and you've got the repeated number.

Comment: Ah, missed the "just one" part and thought this was for the more general "some number of elements are duplicated" case.