# Finding first duplicated element in linear time

Tags: arrays, algorithm

**DISCLAIMER: This is NOT a homework and neither I'm asking you to provide working code for this question.**

Hi folks, I'm studying a problem with a particular property that allows to solve it in linear time **with O(1) additional memory**.

Here is the problem:

> Given an array "A" of size N with elements **ranging from 1 to N**, find the
>   duplicated element in linear time with constant space of additional memory.
>
> In case of more than one duplicated pair, return the one that the
>   second element has the lower index.
>
> If there are no duplicates, return -1.
>
> Examples:
>
> - A = [1, 2, 3, 4] --> -1
> - A = [1, 1, 3] --> 1
> - A = [3, 3, 1, 1, 5] --> 1

This problem is very easy to solve using a map and counting frequencies, but I'm curious about using only O(1) of extra memory...

I know that the sum of `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + N = (N*(N + 1)) / 2` and this fact may help with this problem but I really can't see how can I do better than my existing solution.

If anyone could shed some light on this for me, it would be awesome!

Comment: There is a well known problem of finding a single duplicate if the elements range from 1 to N-1, for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117388/finding-out-the-duplicate-element-in-an-array?rq=1).  I wonder if one of these techniques can be extended?  If you are allowed to modify the array, instead look at [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739024/finding-duplicates-in-on-time-and-o1-space)

Comment: many thanks for the link! I wasn't aware of similar questions here on SO. sorry for the duplicate! thank you very much! I certainly learned something with the provided links :-)