# What does a[a[]] do in C?

Tags: c, arrays

```
for (int i = 0; i< n; i++)
    arr[arr[i]%k] += k;
```

I'm new to programming and I came across this piece of code [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-maximum-repeating-number-in-ok-time/). Can anyone explain what it does?

Comment: You may refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739024/finding-duplicates-in-on-time-and-o1-space

Comment: Read a good C programming book (and C++ is not C). Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`). Run the code step by step in a debugger (`gdb`)

Comment: I understand that it is adding k to the value. It's the arr[arr[i]] part that i find confusing.

Comment: @PapluTaplu: Just break it down into simple expressions. It's reading an array element (at index `i`), performing a calculation on it (reducing it modulo `k`), using the result as another array index, and adding `k` to the element at that index.

Comment: The page you linked to seems to have a pretty thorough explanation of what the code does.  What exactly are you confused about?

Comment: Also worth mentioning that adding k to elements you encounter doesn't change the indices they point to, so essentially this code goes over the array in a recurring manner using the indices stored, and counts (in multiplication of k) how many times you visit each entry within n steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translate to:

```
for (int i = 0; i< n; i++) {
    int temp1 = arr[i];
    int temp2 = temp1%k;
    int temp3 = arr[temp2];
    arr[temp2] = temp3+k;
}
```

Edit: thanks for the correction @R Sahu

Comment: `temp1=arr[i]%k` and `arr[temp1] = arr[temp1]+k;` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

The loop

```
for (int i = 0; i< n; i++)
    arr[arr[i]%k] += k;
```

is equivalent to

```
for (int i = 0; i< n; i++)
{
   int temp1 = arr[i];
   int temp2 = temp1%k;
   arr[temp2] = arr[temp2]+k;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr[arr[i]%k] += k;

arr // (array)
arr[i]; // hereinafter "x"  (The i-th element of the array)
x%k; // hereinafter "res" (result of the modulo)
arr[res]; //(The res-th element of the array)
```