# Remove duplicate characters from a string without using additional buffer

Tags: java, string

I am working on an interview question where I need to remove duplicate characters from the String without using additional buffer.

Below is the code I have but it's not giving right output for this string `"aabbab"`. Is there anything wrong in below code?

```
  private static void removeDuplicates(char[] str) {
    if (str == null)
      return;
    int len = str.length;
    if (len < 2)
      return;

    int tail = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < len; ++i) {
      int j;
      for (j = 0; j < tail; ++j) {
        if (str[i] == str[j])
          break;
      }
      if (j == tail) {
        str[tail] = str[i];
        ++tail;
      }
    }
    str[tail] = 0;
  }
```

I am not able to figure out what is wrong in the above code after debugging.

Comment: `if (str[i] == str[j])
          break;` It looks like when you find a dupe you just `break`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding duplicates in O(n) time and O(1) space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739024/finding-duplicates-in-on-time-and-o1-space)

Comment: Instead of iterating each character to remove duplicate string. you can use regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to do like this

```
if (str == null)
        return;
int len = str.length;
if (len < 2)
    return;
for(int i = 0; i <len; i++) {
    for(int j = i+1; j<len; j++) {
        if(str[i] == str[j]) {
            str[j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

But the result will look like this `a[space]b[space][space][space]` because we just set the character to 0.

Answer (score 0):

This question's time complexity is O(n^2).

But if your input char array has some restrict， such as char array is between 'a' and 'z'. It has O(n) method to solve.

The idea of that is use bits of one variable to save charactor appeared.

```
void removeDuplicate(char s[])
{
    int len = strlen(s);
    if(len < 2) return;
    int check = 0, p = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        int v = (int)(s[i]-'a');
        if((check & (1 << v))==0)
        {
            s[p++] = s[i];
            check |= (1 << v);
        }
    }
    s[p] = '\0';
}
```

ps. This code is from other website.

Answer (score 0):

So basically we will mark the duplicates first with some special characters and then we need to remove those special characters. Time complexity would be O(n^2).

```
char[] str = "aabbabcdcd".toCharArray();
        int len = str.length;
        if (len < 2)
          return;
```

Step-1, Mark the positions with some special characters like `0` or `$`

```
for (int i = 0; i < len-1; ++i) {
            for(int j=i+1;j<len;j++)
            {
                if(str[i]==str[j])
                {
                    str[j]=0; //<---mark the positions      
                }
            }
        }
```

> Output: a b   cd

Step-2, We need to remove those inner black space

```
int j;


for(int i=1;i<len-1;i++)
{
  if(str[i]==0)
  {
      for(j=i+1;j<len;j++)
      {
          if(str[j]!=0)
          {
              break;  
          }
      }
      if(j!=len)  //<-----replace with blank
      {
        str[i] = str[j];  
        str[j]=0;  
      }

  }


}
```

> Output: abcd